# No sound in video downloaded from youtube using pytube

Tags: python-3.x, pytube

I'm able to download the video using "pytube" library but, the downloaded *video* has no **sound** in playback!

Here's what I've tried...

```
"""
Developer: @skywalkerSam
Aim: To download youtube videos...
Date: 12022.07.13.03:00
"""

from pytube import YouTube


yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJQP7kiw5Fk", use_oauth=True, allow_oauth_cache=True)


def info():
    print("\nTitle: ", yt.title)
    print("Views: ", yt.views)
    # print("Description: \t", yt.description)
    print("Thumbnail: ", yt.thumbnail_url)
    print('Stream Options: \n', yt.streams.filter().order_by('resolution').desc(), '\n')


def download():
    yt.streams.filter(progressive=True)
    stream = yt.streams.get_by_itag(399)
    print("\nProcessing Your Request, Please Wait...\n")
    stream.download(output_path="C:\\Users\\samsk\\Downloads\\Youtube\\")
    print("\nDownload Complete :) \n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        info()
        download()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\n\n Operation Cancelled By User :( \n")
        exit()
    except Exception as e:
        print("\nError: ", e)
```

Please help me with this, Thank You...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working script to download videos from youtube, install required modules on your system, and change youtube URLs (if you want) and You're good to go

```
import moviepy.editor as mpe
import os
import pytube

vname = "clip.mp4"
aname = "audio.mp3"

# Download video and rename
video = pytube.YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJQP7kiw5Fk").streams.filter(
    subtype='mp4', res="1080p").first().download()
os.rename(video, vname)

# Download audio and rename
audio = pytube.YouTube(
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJQP7kiw5Fk").streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download()
os.rename(audio, aname)

# Setting the audio to the video
video = mpe.VideoFileClip(vname)
audio = mpe.AudioFileClip(aname)
final = video.set_audio(audio)

# Output result
final.write_videofile("video.mp4")

# Delete video and audio to keep the result
os.remove(vname)
os.remove(aname)
```

Takes a bit of time to compile audio & video together. So, give it some time...

Answer (score 0):

You must download the audio and video to combine the two

I did it with moviepy:

```
import moviepy.editor as mpe

vname = "clip.mp4"
aname = "audio.mp3"

# Download video and rename
video = pytube.YouTube(url).streams.filter(subtype='mp4', res="1080p").first().download()
os.rename(video, vname)

# Download audio and rename
audio = pytube.YouTube(url).streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download()
os.rename(audio, aname)

# Setting the audio to the video
video = mpe.VideoFileClip(vname)
audio = mpe.AudioFileClip(aname)
final = video.set_audio(audio)

# Output result
final.write_videofile("video.mp4")

# Delete video and audio to keep the result
os.remove(vname)
os.remove(aname)
```

Comment: I had to import pytube and os modules too. Took a bit of time to compile audio and video together but yeah, it works  :)